# How to Remove last siblings with same attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html,

```js
$( "#test" ).last().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="test">thid2</label>
<label id="test" >this3</label>
<label id="test" >this4</label>
```

I know duplicate id is not allowed.
But Yes, here is the case 
*because HTML is coming from a database that will combine multiple HTML values into one*.

I want to remove the last label with id **test**.

Can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you not change the code which is creating the duplicate element ids? It would be a far better solution that using JS as a band-aid

Comment: It is like, project is already created, and its css is already written with respect to those ids. I don't know where it those ids or classes are being used. I thought of it at first site. But its like, I cant make changes in current code.

Comment: Well, you can, you just don't want to :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I can. But access denied. My TL don't want me to ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 
[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
 to get all elements with same `id`, anyways it's bad practice to use duplicate id instead use class for a group of elements.

```js
$("[id='test']").last().remove();
// or $("[id='test']:last").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="test">thid2</label>
<label id="test">this3</label>
<label id="test">this4</label>
```

Comment: Suuuuperrrr mate !!!! Thanks a ton !!! I know mate using ids is bad practice. But there are several html snippets, by using them, I will make a single html snippet. Thats why I cant do anything

Comment: don't need to use javascript. use only css. look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute matching:

```
$("[id=test]")
```

Snippet:

```js
$("[id=test]").last().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="test">thid2</label>
<label id="test" >this3</label>
<label id="test" >this4</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix records in DB. But you can hide last element by

```
<style> label#test:last-child { display:none } </style>


<div class="parent">
  <label id="test">thid2</label>
  <label id="test" >this3</label>
  <label id="test" >this4</label>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84t7kjbq/2/)

Comment: Nice alternative, but for arguments sake, the requirement was to *remove* the elements, not just hide them.  While it might have the same effect to the user, if there's any other parsing/etc on the page, they're still available (eg to jquery).

Comment: if you count items or something else with js,  yes you need to remove item from DOM and using js better. I think my approach is enough for this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
$( "#test:nth-last-child(2)" ).remove();